# what will android do if it didn't find the target files in the best matching resources folder?

Tags: android, android-layout

As http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html said, Android finding the best matching resource folder at runtime, depending on the current device configuration.

for example:

> drawable/
>   drawable-en/
>   drawable-fr-rCA/
>   drawable-en-port/
>   drawable-en-notouch-12key/
>   drawable-port-ldpi/
>   drawable-port-notouch-12key/

And assume the following is the device configuration:

> Locale = en-GB
>   Screen orientation = port
>   Screen pixel density = hdpi
>   Touchscreen type = notouch
>   Primary text input method = 12key

By comparing the device configuration to the available alternative resources, Android selects drawables from `drawable-en-port/`.

What if I want to use an xml `foo.png` which not in the `drawable-en-port/` but in the `drawable/`? According to the document, folder except `drawable-en-port/` were eliminated.

What will android do if it didn't find the target files in the best matching resources folder?

Answer (score 1):

If android will not found resource in `drawable-en-port/` will use it from `drawable-en/`. If there will be no drawable in `drawable-en/` will use from default folder `drawable/`.

You can verify this for e.g. with creating one string resource

in `values/`

```
<string name="test_value">value default</string>
```

in `values-en/`

```
<string name="test_value">value en</string>
```

in `values-en-port/`

```
<string name="test_value">value en port</string>
```

Then use in your layout

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/test_value" />
```

In portrait mode and EN locale you should see "value en port". If you delete this value from `values-en-port/` and run app again, best matching folder will be still `values-en-port/` but because there will be no such string resource it will be used from `values-en/`. You can then try also to delete string from `values-en/` and you should see default one "value default" in app.

Comment: why `drawable/` not `drawable-en/` ?

Comment: you mean android will trace back from the current best matching path?

Comment: Yes, as described in example.